# How to use Bool variable

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, boolean-logic

Read in a 3-character string from input into variable userCode. Declare a boolean variable isValid and set isValid to true if the second and third characters of userCode are both digits. Otherwise, set isValid to false.

What it is in Bold is what I have to fill in. The rest is apart of the question.

```
int main() {
string userCode;

bool isValid;
getline(cin, userCode);

if (isdigit(userCode[2])){  
   isValid = true;
   userCode = isValid;
}
if (isdigit(userCode[3])){
   isValid = true;
   userCode = isValid;
}
else {
   bool isValid = false;
}

if (isValid) {
   cout << "Valid passcode" << endl;
}
else {
   cout << "Invalid passcode" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? (And maybe set `isValid` to false when you declare it and check **both** digits.... with an and (`&&`)

Comment: nothing is in bold - read your question please!

Comment: `bool isValid = false;` is declaring a new local variable, which is immediatly discarded at the end of the `else` branch.

Comment: I feel like it wouldn't have been so difficult to include the includes and make this an actual [mre]. Otherwise I second @doctorlove's suggestion. The `bool` should be initialized to `false`, and you have to be convinced to make it `true`.

Comment: You cannot use markup within a code formatting block. The asterisks `*` are simply displayed as text. You should remove them.

Comment: If you hold off creating `isValid` until after you've gotten the input you can create it and initialize it all in one place: `bool isValid = /* figure out whether it's valid */`.

Comment: Also, don't assign to `userCode` in those `if` statements. After the `getline` there's nothing that needs to be done to it.

Comment: Also, the second and third characters in `userCode` are `userCode[1]` and `userCode[2]`, not `userCode[2]` and `userCode[3]`. Index values in C++ start at 0; that takes some getting used to, but there are good reasons for it.

Comment: Listen everyone Im new to the class. @doctorlove I tried it without using ' bool isValid = False' and it gave me less errors then what I have before. Whenever I submit what I have it tells me that every output is "Valid passcode" when others should be "invalid passcode".

Comment: @sweenish oh but it is difficult. Sorry I dont automatically know code bruh.

Comment: oh yea I know about the 0 just forgot to apply to that here. And do you imply that I declare the bool isValid until after my ifs. Im new to this. @PeteBecker

Comment: @PeteBecker I started it now with bool isValid = false;         What else do I change in my ifs statements ?

Comment: You probably should verify that `userCode.size()` is at least 3 before accessing `userCode[2]`

Comment: Difficult to read (all that stuff they show you when you register is so you can ask good questions), and include lines of code that were already there? Sure. That's more difficult than cutting down your code. It's not about "automatically know(ing) code, bruh," it's about reading instructions and following them.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Yet another newbie-hostile close vote. Yes, the code is quite sloppy, but the problem(s) is clear. What "details or clarity" do the close voters want?

Comment: @PeteBecker A specific programming question would be a great start. The only question I can find is: _"How to use Bool variable"_ but I can also find `bool isValid;`, `isValid = true;` and `if (isValid) {`, so obviously that's not the actual question. According to [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it's too broad to the dump the broken code without specific question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- you've unintentionally made my point: it's obvious what the problem is, and, with a bit of common sense, it's equally clear what the question is. Insisting that there be a sentence with a question mark is just rationalizing hostility.

Comment: @PeteBecker The implicit question is: "Here is my broken code. I can't fix. Please fix my code". That's too broad and off-topic. Maybe it's the wrong close-reason, but the question should be closed and deleted.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- "closed and deleted" -- wow. Harsh. Amazing that several people offered constructive comments and one person gave a correct answer to such a horrible question.

Comment: @PeteBecker The goal of Stackoverflow is to collect questions and answers for future users, not to help one individual. Questions like this won't help anyone, because they don't contain a specific programming problem. It's just asking for individual debugging help. This question could be a great question on other platforms or forums, but not on Stackoverflow. It's very unlikely that someone with a similar problem could find this question and use the answer. It's not even a C++ related question, but a problem with the algorithm.

Comment: @PeteBecker At the bottom of [ask] you can find a link to [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), a website that explains why such questions aren't helpful and are off-topic.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- thank you for your input. Your concerns have been noted.

Answer (score 4):

The second and third characters are at [1] and [2]. You should start with isvalid equal to true. Then test those two characters if either one is not a digit.

```
 bool isvalid = true;
 if(!isdigit(userCode[1]) || ! isdigit(userCode[2]))
     isvalid = false;
 if(isvalid)
    cout << "good\n";
 else 
    cout << "bad\n";
```

or with the logic the other way round

```
 bool isvalid = false;
 if(isdigit(userCode[1]) && isdigit(userCode[2]))
     isvalid = true;
 if(isvalid)
    cout << "good\n";
 else 
    cout << "bad\n";
```

Comment: did this and still dosnt work :(

Comment: I prefer to prove something is true than prove it's false. In other words, assume the worst and convince yourself things are good. In this scenario, it would allow you to get rid of the `!`s, and simplify the code.